# How to nested SQL Queries?

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT TOP 1 CONTENT WHERE ID=ID(in the table A) FROM B) AS Content 
    FROM A
```

I want to query some data from a table base on the ID in each of the A, and query some other data by the ID at the same time, then transfer it as a new column.

Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Sample data o provide exact solution....

Comment: Erm... isn't this just a join?

Comment: If you want to join content from two tables, just do a `JOIN`. Otherwise, define what `some data` means

Comment: @Liath depends on how many rows are in A and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a correlated query, which can look like (example for SQL Server, based on your usage of TOP n):

```
SELECT      A.ID, 
            (SELECT TOP 1
                        CONTENT 
            FROM        B
            WHERE       B.ID = A.ID
            ) AS Content 
FROM        A
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON(a.ID=b.ID)
```

There is also LEFT and RIGHT JOIN and a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: There was a `TOP 1` clause in Alen's query, so this is not equivalent